# get string from html file and compare with a saved text

Tags: awk, sh

what i want is:
read IP address from html
if this IP is different from saved IP send email
save IP to file

what i have is this in a html file:

> ```
> Current IP CheckCurrent IP
>  Address: 186.6.201.19 
>  on date: Tue Feb 24 06:00:02
>  AST 2015
> ```

the time changes so i cannot do a file compare

i have already 
$ awk '/Current IP Address: /{b=$6}END{print b}' '/home/share/wifi.jd/updates/ipcheck.html'

the 'print b' gives nicely the value of 'b' (the IP address) as response

but now i have to compare this 'b' to the value/string from file 'ipcheck.dat' 
if is not the same send email to: what@ever.now
save new 'b' to 'ipcheck.dat'

i hope this this is a bit clear to show my problem

Answer (score 0):

Why not try something like with grep as below:

```
grep $b ipcheck.dat
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]
then
    echo $b >> ipcheck.dat
fi
```

Comment: looks easy, but it stops on the grep command with no error, just waiting

Comment: maybe this is easier .. the html that needs to be checked for ip changes is here at an external location .. http://www.dunhill.ws/myip/index.html .. all that i need is that i get an email at the moment when the IPaddress changes